# SETUID at filesystem level

Tags: c, linux, zsh, archlinux, setuid

Suppose we are looking at the following scenario:

File saymyname.c (includes omitted)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    system("whoami");   
}
```

Build and set permission bits:

```
cake@lie> gcc saymyname.c -o saymyname
cake@lie> sudo chown root:root saymyname
cake@lie> sudo chmod u+s saymyname
cake@lie> ./saymyname
cake
```

Every resource under the sun tells me that setting the `s` permission on the user-column should make the program execute with the owner's privileges, not the calling user's. Why does `system("whoami");` return `cake`?

Modifying the program to set the UID manually like so:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    setuid(geteuid());
    system("whoami");   
}
```

Yields the expected result

```
cake@lie> ./saymyname
root
```

Some resources claim that the SUID and GUID bits are often ignored. Is this why the observed behavior occurs? If so, is there a way to make it behave as if it was executed by root without `setuid(.)`?

Comment: One of the better resources is Chen, Wagner and Dean's [Setuid Demystified](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/TEACHING/comp_sec_F04/downloads/setuid.pdf).

Comment: No chance with id either. Permissions `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root cake 17K Dec  5 04:05 saymyname`, `id` output: `uid=1000(cake) gid=1001(cake) groups=1001(cake),998(wheel),1000(autologin)`. Getting more puzzled by the minute now.

Comment: `system` runs a shell. The shell might be dropping privileges. Try `execlp("id","id",(char *)0)`

Comment: No luck on `execlp` either. Same result as plain `system()`

Comment: I can't reproduce that, meaning it will never print `root`. Tip: use `strace -f ./saymyname` to see the system calls being made and their results.

Comment: It prints root if I run it with sudo for that matter. Feels like it's time to namedrop the kernel and shell: `Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.19.4-arch1-1-ARCH` `Shell: zsh 5.6.2`

Comment: Of course it prints `root` if you run it with sudo :)

Comment: Is it coreutils `id`? If not, are you sure it would print euid if it found euid different from ruid?

Comment: It technically doesn't `never print root` if there is a way to make it print root ;). Back on topic; here's what `strace` has to say https://pastebin.com/ebSDCzf0 . Other than some rather unexpected journey through my $PATH there isn't much I can decipher from it. And it's the plain old `/usr/bin/id` that came with the distro for all I know.

Comment: `strace` cancels setuid, because setuid programs don't necessarily want all their internals exposed to their callers.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley That's good to know. Following the man page, `sudo strace -u cake -f ./saymyname` can be used here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Georg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53625004/171318) is technically correct <sup>1</sup>, but it is worth to mention that the `system(3)` man page explicitly states that the use of `system()` in setuid programs is not recommended:

> **Do not use system() from a program with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges, because strange values for some environment variables might
>          be  used  to subvert system integrity.  Use the exec(3) family of functions instead, but not execlp(3) or execvp(3)**.  system() will not, in
>          fact, work properly from programs with set-user-ID or set-group-ID privileges on systems on which /bin/sh is bash version [>=]2, since  bash  2
>          drops privileges on startup.  (Debian uses a modified bash which does not do this when invoked as sh.)

This is especially relevant in your example as you are calling `whoami` without the full path. Imagine the following scenario (as unprivileged user):

```
> whoami cat << 'EOF'
#!/bin/not-bash :)
echo "I'm root! let's clean up some trash ..."
# rm -rf /
EOF
chmod +x whoami

PATH="${PWD}" ./saymyname
```

That means, instead of changing the system shell (or using Debian), the code should just use `exec()`, like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    execl("/usr/bin/whoami", "whoami", NULL);   
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [newer versions of `dash` on Ubuntu will also drop privileges](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dash/+bug/1215660)

Comment: Hah. Let this be a warning to everyone to just RTFM, I guess.

Comment: I must say that I have learned a lot in this thread. (Or at least I'm now aware that I know nothing :) ) Especially the pdf linked by jww in the first comment below your question is very interesting to read (and extremely well done)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like bash, which is executed by system(), drops the privileges. In my tests, replacing the symbolic link /bin/sh pointing to dash (instead of bash) made it work as expected.

Also with bash,

```
execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "whoami", NULL);
```

gives cake, whereas

```
execl("/usr/bin/whoami", "whoami", NULL);
```

gives root.

Comment: Spot on. As the man pages point out, `system()` calls `/bin/sh` (just like exec* family when the file isn't immediately found) which, in my case, is indeed `/bin/bash`, which does drop privileges.
Before I mark your answer as correct: Do you know a way to prevent it from doing that, or is it just "a security feature"? After all, running it with `sudo` successfully passes on the privileges to `bash`, which is what I would expect the SETUID'd program to do too.

Comment: That's because when you run the program with sudo, the uid and euid are 0. It's like running `sudo whoami`

Comment: In practice, I also wouldn't use the setuid bit, but edit /etc/sudoers file instead.